# remove specific path from url path by regexp

Tags: regex, go

There are many ways to remove specific string by Golang.
But I need to use regexp in this time.

```
func Replace(path, from, to string) string {
    reg, _ := re.Compile(from)
    if reg.MatchString(path) {
        return reg.ReplaceAllString(path, to)
    }
    return "error"
}

//This pattern is OK
fmt.Println(Replace("/nl/amsterdam/area2/area1", `\/+(?:area1|area2).+(/|\z)`, "$1"))
// Output: /nl/amsterdam

//What is wrong??
fmt.Println(Replace("/nl/amsterdam/area2", `\/+(?:area1|area2).+(/|\z)`, "$1"))
// Output: error
// I expect => /nl/amsterdam

fmt.Println(Replace("/nl/amsterdam/area2", `\/+(?:area1|area2)(/|\z)`, "$1"))
// Output: /nl/amsterdam
// This pattern seems OK, but when path is `/nl/amsterdam/area2/area1`, it doesn't work as I expected like the next pattern.

fmt.Println(Replace("/nl/amsterdam/area2/area1", `\/+(?:area1|area2)(/|\z)`, "$1"))
// Output: /nl/amsterdam/area1
// I wanna get /nl/amsterdam
```

How many targets is included in path is changeable.

Comment: Please explain the requirements, it is hard to deduce them from these examples. Probably, you want to use `\`(?:/(?:area1|area2))+(/|$)\`` regex.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew you are great! That's what I wanted to do!

Comment: Ok, I added as an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(?:/(?:area1|area2))+(/|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4nDD1/1).

**Details**

- `(?:/(?:area1|area2))+` - 1 or more occurrences of the following sequence:

  - `/` - a `/` char (no need to escape it in the Go regex patterns)
  - `(?:area1|area2)` - a non-capturing group matching either `area1` or `area2` (also can be replaced with `area[12]` or just `area\d+` to match `area` and 1+ digits)
- `(/|$)` - Group 1: either `/` or end of string (`\z` will match the very end of string).